# Difference between not constructive and obsolete flags

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

When flagging comments it is possible to flag comments as either "not constructive" or "obsolete" among other things. If you delete a comment or make an edit that makes another comment obsolete and no longer constructive, I think it is easiest for the moderators if the comment is flagged as obsolete instead of not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. However, some users may not see the deleted comments, and know that they are there. Therefore, we may have to tolerate some mismarking.

However, if the comment looks like it's somewhat relevant, it's probably better to mark it "obsolete" than "non-constructive" as a precaution.

Answer (score 1):

I have been interpreting "not constructive" as being more along the lines of [destructive criticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varieties_of_criticism#Destructive_criticism).  Under that interpretation, anything that was *ever* constructive would still be constructive, but might become obsolete.  I do not know, however, the degree to which others agree with this interpretation.

Comment: What you call "destructive criticism" would be better flagged as "rude or offensive" (at least, by the example on Wikipedia right now)

Comment: Maybe I've been setting too high a bar for "rude or offensive": that I've been trying to interpret as "to everybody" rather than just to myself...

Comment: I like potatoes!

Comment: ^ That is not constructive.

Comment: @Compass Well played.  I think I should adjust my personal filter, and maybe delete this post...

Comment: Comments that definitely violate the [be nice](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) rule are "rude or offensive."